# How to write a formula to count brown cell as 0.5 rather that 1?

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement is I want to calculate brown colored cell as 0.5 and want to update my attendance count as +0.5.
As per the current code I am getting the count of a specific colour as 1 but I want to add one more colour which should count as 0.5 rather than 1.

PF below macro used as of now:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

In CELL I am using `Countccolor` function like `=CountCcolor(E2:AI2,$B$46)`

By using above cell B46 is yellow coloured cell which is counted as 1.
But I want to calculate B47 cell as 0.5 rather than 1.

Please help on the above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a very backwards way of doing it. Why not populate the cells with 0.5 and 1 in the first place, and conditionally format them to display the colour?

Comment: actually I was trying to automate my attendance sheet in which I want to calculate a brown colour cell with 0.5 working days and consider 0.5 days in leave.

Comment: Also request you to please share the conditional format fomula which I can try in my attendance sheet.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: this 0.5 is required for half day in the attendance sheet

Answer (score 0):

Just add another criteria and create another `If` condition to see if it's that color:

```
Dim datax As Range
Dim xcolor As Long, brown As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
brown = 53 'the default brown color index

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    ElseIf datax.Interior.ColorIndex = brown Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 0.5
    End If
Next datax

End Function
```